# Server Files in JTree

Tags: java, swing, file, server, jtree

I want to take this code below and instead of using the C drive I want to put my server information there to display the file tree from a server. What needs to be changed to accomplish that?

```
    public void Display2(){

        File fileRoot = new File("C:/");
        root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new FileNode(fileRoot));
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
         Scroll2.setViewportView(tree);
        CreateChildNodes ccn = 
        new CreateChildNodes(fileRoot, root);
        new Thread(ccn).start();

        if (FileToSend.getText().isEmpty()){
          tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

              @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        FileToSend.setText(e.getPath().toString());
        U= true;
        D= false;
    }
});        
        }
        // if(!FileToSend.getText().isEmpty()){
             else{
       tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

              @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
       SendTo.setText(e.getPath().toString());
       D=true;
       U=false;
    }
});         
    }}
```

Comment: Does the server even provide information on the directory & file structure? In most cases, doing so is a security hole.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes it does. I know how to get the information from the server and I have gotten that but now I need to add it to a UI scrollpane like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the server in order to do that.

There are many ways to do so, one of which I am familiar with is Sockets.

You need to have a server connection point running on the machine you want to connect to. I.E) 127.0.0.1 port 10

---

```
int port = 10;
```

Server End:

```
SocketServer server = new SocketServer(port);
Socket incommingClient = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectOutputStream out =
    new ObjectOutputStream (incommingClient .getOutputStream(), true);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream (
    new InputStreamReader(incommingClient .getInputStream()));
```

---

Client End:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
/**
 * Look up how to connect to a java socket server and how java server/client programs work */
/** Open up the IO Streams of the socket to the host and use the following objects to transfer your files */
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
```

---

Note that inorder to transfer files over the internet the java objects must be serialized. (Implementing Serializable)

The code here may not be exact, but it should get you started.

For more information, use the following links.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

https://www.journaldev.com/741/java-socket-programming-server-client